# JSON AsyncTask ( get pictures of the site invisible for the user and very smoothly)

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am new to Android development. In my project I'm trying to get data from a site and show that data in a listview.

I am getting String data with httpGet and I'm parsing it with json and then put the data in adapter to show. However, it doesn't look smooth and it's working very slowly.

I should get 10 initial elements, and then when scrolling down get new 10 elements (but very smoothly).

```
    videoList = new ArrayList<Videos>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute(
    "http://speechyard.com/api/content/?type=videolist&page=1&perPage=10");
    ListView listview = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
    VideoAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Videos> objects)
    adapter = new VideoAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.content_row,  videoList);

    listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        } @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
           int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
           if(lastItem +2> pageNumber*10) {

               pageNumber+=1;
               Log.d(TAG,pageNumber.toString());

            new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://speechyard.com/api/content/?type=videolist&page="+pageNumber+"&perPage=10");
           }}});
}

     //*******get data from http
     class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    //*****set progress dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    //*************HTTP Get  save in String data
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {//------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

       //**********Optimization String data for JSON parsing

                String newdata="{\"video\":"+data+"}";

                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(newdata);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("video");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Videos video = new Videos();
                    video.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    video.setId(object.getString("id"));
                    video.setCategory(object.getString("category"));
                    video.setTime(object.getString("time"));
                    video.setSubtitles(object.getString("subtitles"));
                    video.setYoutube(object.getString("youtube"));
                    video.setImage(object.getString("image"));
                    videoList.add(video);
                    }

                return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

**suggestion : Use HttpURLConnection !**

**1. create JSONParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser extends Thread 
{
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        URL myUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
        connection.connect();
        is = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        is = null;
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        json = "";
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        jObj = null;
    }
    return jObj;
}
```

}

2. Use like this.

   private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask 
   {

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() 
   {
   }

   @Override
   protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) 
   {
       JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
       JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
       return json;    
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
   {
       //json.get......
   }
   ```

Comment: This code is not good @HWANG, because there is no need that the JSONParser extends from Thread. The doInBackground is already running in the background thread and also please avoid using Threads directly by yourself as Android SDK provides a lot of ways to handle multi task operations.

Comment: @Proverbio it's only sample code. sometimes developer not use AsyncTask

Comment: Sorry anyway you can not use a JSONParser that extends from a Thread. It's not a good practise at all. Ask your friends, workmates or just do some research.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a lot of things you could be doing better.

The best way to load data onto a Fragment is using an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) (because you want to load a list) and a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Your App could get so much better if you use [Google Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) as network provider and [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for JSON so you don't need to write this kind of code

```
 Videos video = new Videos();
 video.setName(object.getString("name"));
 video.setId(object.getString("id"));
```

Fragments should be only used to display data, not to get it from network or have network code on the Fragment. To get data from the server you always need to be working with a Loader.

Basically you need to create a Loader class that extends from `AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<Videos>>` and your fragment needs to implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Videos>>` on the Loader `public ArrayList<Videos> loadInBackground()` you should be requesting the data from server and returning an ArrayList of Videos.